# How to add custom SP calls to SSMS toolbar

Tags: ssms, ssms-2014, ssms-2016

Recently I've found out, that there's an option to include most commonly used queries to be executed by clicking a button on SSMS toolbar.

You can do that by following these steps:

1. Right mouse click on toolbar
2. Click Customize
3. Create new toolbar
4. Modify it
5. Add Command
6. Under Query categories there's option to add up to 9 Custom SPs

Now when I came here, things look like that:
[image]

However I'm struggling on how to add the actual procedure, that needs to be executed.

There's an option to add multiple SPs:

1. Custom SP 1
2. Custom SP 2
3. ...
4. `sp_help`
5. `sp_lock`
6. `sp_who`

How do I assign my procedure to be `Custom SP 1`, for instance?

To be clear: My goal is to have a button in SSMS toolbar, which would execute my desired procedure (query) on click.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a great question imo, but to do this it's an awful way you'll have to go.

Unfortunately i have the German version of SSMS, so my screens might confuse you a little.

Following you can see a guide:

[image: First Step]
The Options-Window

[image: Step two]
Select a free Shortcut

[image: Final]
Assign to Toolbar

This seems a bit uncomfortable, but this is the only way i know / can imagine on how to do this.

Let me know if this helps! Cheers

Comment: Yep, that was nasty but this is what exactly I was looking for. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

English version of SSMS
Go to Tools-> options
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to offset the "Custom SP #" button by 1.
ie I've assigned a command to Query Shortcut "Ctrl + 9" which will be run when I use the "Custom SP 8" command to add to the toolbar.

[image]